# How to transfer a single user profile and nothing else with USMT 10?

Tags: windows-10, usmt

What is the quickest and easiest way to transfer a user profile from one Windows 10 Professional x64 workgroup PC to another Windows 10 Professional x64 workgroup PC with USMT 10, without copying anything else besides that one user profile?

Both PC's are pretty much identical, so there is no point in copying application settings or folders other than that one user profile.

What has to be edited in the USMT configuration files to accomplish this?

I'm fairly comfortable with USMT and have used it to move a whole PC. Just not a single user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally, I would think that using the USMT just to migrate one user profile might be a bit of overkill. Under similar circumstances, I would backup the contents of the traditional folders (Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Favorites, Music, Pictures, Videos) to a USB drive, ensure that all of their [Windows 10 sync settings](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4077-sync-settings-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) were turned on, and verify that their Firefox sync and/or Chrome sync were configured properly, then restore on the new computer. The entire process is relatively simple, fast, and reliable.

Comment: Except for Outlook. USMT 10 does Outlook correctly. Finally.

Comment: I actually did take that into account, but since you emphasized that these Windows 10 machines are in a workgroup (versus a domain), I assumed that wouldn't be too difficult.  On my Windows 10 workgroup we are utilizing Outlook 2016 within Office 365, and as a result virtually all of our pertinent data and settings are retained.  We just need to input our e-mail address and password.

Answer (score 0):

I would just omit the *MigApp.xml*,only using *MigUser.xml* and maybe include [Ehlertec's](http://ehlertech.com/customxmls/) *ExcludeSystemFolders.xml*

In below example a user, *Henny* is migrated.

scanstate "C:\USMTstore" /i:"C:\USMTstore\ExcludeSystemFolders.xml" /i:"C:\USMTstore\MigUser.xml" /progress:"C:\Users\the\AppData\Local\Temp\USMTprog.log" /l:"C:\Users\the\AppData\Local\Temp\USMTscan.log" /listfiles:"C:\USMTstore\FilesList.log"  /vsc /o /localonly /c /ue:** /ui:"Henny" /efs:decryptcopy

The above is "stolen" directly from Ehlertech's GUI for USMT.. :-)